# Is there a reason why a label might be visible on one PC but not on another?

Tags: c#, .net, text, label, splash-screen

I am following the tutorial posted [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5454/A-Pretty-Good-Splash-Screen-in-C?), which has been updated for .NET 3.5 [here](http://www.mahingupta.com/mahingupta/blog/post/2009/07/26/Winforms-splash-screen-Great-work-by-Tom.aspx). I am using .NET 4.0 and the splash screen works wonderfully on both my laptop, and my colleague's laptop. But if we move to our test pc, for some reason the labels do not show up on the splash form. We put a logger in there, and I can see that the label is set to Visible, it is getting the updated text, and it has a positive size.

What could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: Are you moving the source code/compiling or are you moving the executable itself?

Comment: This is due to the windows theme settings. Your label might be pushed off the screen or whatever due to margins, padding, borders, etc..

Comment: Is there anyway to force it to stay on the image that is a fixed size, regardless of the theme / accessibility settings? And image is an image is an image, so the text should always sit on the image in the same spot.

Comment: Found a solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10644298/1233949

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem about a week ago. In my case the color of the text was a system color that varied between systems, try changing the color. It may not be your issue, but it definitely causes the same issue.

Edit: Answering a question you had in your comments, there should be a autosizemode which you can try different modes until you find the one that works best, in my experience, yesterday, none and DPI work the best.

Note: My answers were based on .net 3.5 VB, but to my knowledge they are very similar and both paragraphs should be able to help.

Comment: Thank you for this. I found a similar solution in the link in the comments above, but I wasn't aware of the System Color point. Thanks for the heads up!