# c# scale entire form based on screen resolution

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have an application that is full screen and has multiple panels and layouts which all works fine.  However when testing it on another screen resolution things go wrong.  So far I have been able to adjust everything based on the resolution width but the height has become an issue.  I began scaling everything and realized I would have to re-adjust all of the fonts based on the new label sizes.  There are quite a few labels and textboxes which is a lot of work to do everyone of them.  I have been searching and found Windows WPF, but I've never used it and I really don't want to have to move everything over to it.  I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this without starting over.

Comment: I assume you are using winforms? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autoscalemode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: check out that link, might be of interest.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4089811/17034